# how to use wget on a site with many folders and subfolders

Tags: wget

I try to download [this site](http://tenshi.spb.ru/anime-ost/), with this code:

wget -r -l1 -H -t1 -nd -N -np -A.mp3 -erobots=off tenshi.spb.ru/anime-ost/

But I only get the index and enter inside the first folder, not the subfolder, help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this command to download sites including their subfolders:

wget --mirror -p --convert-links -P . [site address]

A little explanation:

--mirror is a shortcut for -N -r -l inf --no-remove-listing.
--convert-links makes links in downloaded HTML or CSS point to local files
-p allows you to get all images, etc. needed to display HTML pages
-P specifies the next argument is the directory the files will be saved to

I found the command at:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples/

Answer (score 1):

You use `-l 1` also known as `--level=1` which limits recursion to one level. Set that to a higher level to download more pages. BTW, I like long options like --level because its easier to see what you are doing without going back to man pages.